# How to combine cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I am trying to looking at the group

$$\begin{align}A_4=\{\varepsilon&, \begin{pmatrix}1&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}3&4\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1&3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2&4\end{pmatrix}, \\&\begin{pmatrix}1&4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2&3\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1&2&4\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1&3&2\end{pmatrix}, \\&\begin{pmatrix}1&3&4\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1&4&2\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1&4&3\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}2&3&4\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}2&4&3\end{pmatrix} \}\end{align}$$

Now I'm trying to build the subset of $A_4$ that is every element squared. That is $S=\{g^2 \mid g\in A_4\}$.

The problem I am having is I am not sure how to combine two given cycles.

$\begin{pmatrix}1&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}3&4\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}3&4\end{pmatrix}\overset{?}{=}$

$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\end{pmatrix}\overset{?}{=}$

Any help on how to combine these will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll combine the first:

We wish to combine $(1 2)(3 4)(1 2)(3 4)$. Going from right to left (by convention) what happens to $1$? Well, $1$ goes to $2$ and then $2$ goes to $1$. Hence $1 \to 1$. Same thing with $2$: $2 \to 1$ and then $1 \to 2$; i.e. $2 \to 2$. $3,4$ follow similarly. We have that $$(1 2)(3 4)(1 2)(3 4) = (1)(2)(3)(4)$$